# How to restore SSH connection

Tags: server, ssh

I am no longer able to SSH into one of my Ubuntu 16.04 VPS.

```
ssh user@123.123.123.123
ssh: connect to host 123.123.123.123 port 22: No route to host
```

This is after a dist upgrade. It appeared to have gone well, though after I rebooted this issue started.

My host has a "rescue system" which allows me to mount the disk of this VPS in a different OS (Debian). Which means I can modify the files. What should I look for, and what might fix my SSH connection issue? I have no idea how to debug this.

Comment: Can you perform a local console login? Many VPS providers offer a control panel like a kind of VNC connection to the virtual terminal.

Comment: I suspect not. Though I am not sure. How can I find out?

Comment: You need to ask your VPS provider. They have to give you a way to tinker with the machine if something is wrong with the software configuration (e.g. SSH problems).

Comment: E.g. this is a panel feature offered by a VPS provider that I also use: https://1.bp.blogspot.com/-jJLxyRGIBFM/UnYxKyiE-YI/AAAAAAAAE8I/-iDtgDVbTQc/s1600/Console.png

Comment: Apparently there is an in-browser console thing. It however is not giving me an encouraging output: http://img.ctrlv.in/img/16/08/20/57b8847ac0d9d.jpg

Comment: Please try to reboot the server from the hosting control panel while you have the browser-based VNC console active... then when the GRUB menu appears, try to boot into recovery mode and see if that one works.

Comment: I cannot start this when the vps is not running and when I stop my vps it disconnects.

Comment: GRUB shows the menu for several seconds... could you try to stop the server, run it again and open the console shortly after?

Comment: Right. That worked. When booting in recovery mode, I still get the same kernel panic. However when I boot with the previous kernel version it works fine.

Comment: That is relevant information, could you add it to the question?

Comment: The problem is solved now essentially. I ran "dpkg --configure -a" after which I'm able to boot normally again. Not sure how I can mark this as solved now though.

Comment: Write a self answer explaining what you did, then mark it as accepted (you may be required by the site to wait up to 2 days before marking it as accepted).

Answer (score 1):

If you can modify the files, you will want to check on `/etc/sshd_config` and `/etc/ssh_config` to make sure they are configured correctly. These files could have been replaced with the `dist-upgrade` and my not allow `root`, or your user, to log in if not configured correctly.

A console provided by your hosting company would be handy to make sure the service is starting and listening on port 22.

Comment: I checked both files and did not see anything that looks wrong to me. I also verified my public key is in authorized_keys. You're right that it would be good to verify ssh is running. I do not know how to do that though.